# Script is running perfectly on co-workers devices but gives me 'Invalid cross-device link'

Tags: shell, docker-desktop

My script is running perfectly on co-workers devices (MacOSX with Docker Desktop same as me), but gives me every time the same error and **it does not move or only half, the libraries in the `deps` directory**:

```
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/tmp/pip-target-dzwe_2kc/lib/python/numpy' ->
 '/foo/python/numpy'
```

My script :

```
#!/bin/bash
export PKG_DIR='python'
export SIDE_DEPS_DIR='deps'

rm -rf ${PKG_DIR} && mkdir -p ${PKG_DIR}
rm -rf ${SIDE_DEPS_DIR} && mkdir -p ${SIDE_DEPS_DIR}

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/foo -w /foo lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t ${PKG_DIR}

# move stuff to deps
find /${PKG_DIR} -maxdepth 1 -type d \
\( -name "pandas*" -o -name "numpy*" -o -name "numpy.libs*" -o -name "scipy*" -o -name "scipy.libs*" \) -exec mv '{}' ${SIDE_DEPS_DIR} \;

# zip side dependencies
zip -r ge_deps.zip deps
# zip layer
zip -r layers-python38-great-expectations.zip python
```

It's a script which uses a public lambda docker image to create a lambda layer (basically a zip that contains libraries) and which removes unwanted libraries to put them in another folder `deps`.

The above code will use the public Docker image lambci / lambda and will install in the empty `python` directory, libraries which come from a python package which is called 'great-expectations' and which helps to test pipelines of data (which is specified in requirements.txt and is `great-expectations==0.12.7`)

I have been stuck with this problem for a while and have not found a solution.

Comment: seems you may be having some hard linking issues: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79132/invalid-cross-device-link-while-hardlinking-in-the-same-file-system/79161

Comment: Did you ``ln`` any of the folders mentioned in the error by chance? And forgot the ``-s`` flag?

Comment: I didn't linked any folder

Comment: If the source and destination are on different filesystems, this is the error you'd get if you tried to use `rename(2)` to move it, but AFAIK `mv(1)` is supposed to fall back to copying and then deleting in this case.  Do your co-workers have `/tmp` and `/foo` on the same filesystem?

Comment: I've seen that if i create a new directory in / Users / random_name, it works fine.
but if i run the script various times in the same directory it doesn't work anymore,
or if i create a new directory in Users / random_name / Desktop it doesn't works.
And the directories have the access rights

Comment: And the directories have the access rights

Answer (score 3):

Had this exact problem just now.

/tmp and /foo are different devices - /tmp is within the docker OS and /foo is mapped to your local OS.

pip seems to be using shutil.rename() to move the built package from tmp to the final output location (/foo).  This fails because they are different devices.  Ideally pip would use shutil.move() instead, which will deal with a cross-device move.

As a workaround, you can change the temp folder used by PIP by setting TMPDIR before invoking the pip command.  i.e. `export TMPDIR=/foo/tmp` before calling pip in the docker image.  So, the whole command might be something like

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/foo -w /foo lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 \
    /bin/bash -c "export TMPDIR=/foo/tmp && pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t ${PKG_DIR}"
```

(multiple commands soln taken from https://www.edureka.co/community/10736/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-docker-at-once - open to better suggestions!)

This will likely be slower because it's using the local OS for temp files, but it avoids the attempted 'rename' across devices from the temp folder to the final output folder.